# Difference between two row values within the same column based on value in third column in R

Tags: r, difference, spotfire

[Expected Table][1]Thanks for looking into this post.
Trying to find difference between the "Record" value based on baseline visit in R(for spotfire)
For RecordId(10001), Change in Record from Baseline is 4 (Difference of 20 at baseline, 24 at screening) and so on.

```
RecordId Record    Visit           Change in Record from Baseline
10001     20       Baseline     
10001     24       Screening     4
10001     20       Visit 4       0
10001     15       Visit 5       5
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Looks like I cannot upload image or table. Basically for given RecordId, I need to find difference in row values for different visits. I cannot explain issue unless I could update my post with data in table format. Is it anyways possible to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you need the change from baseline for each RecordId.
I think this is doable using Spotfire calculated columns and expressions, so you don't have to involve an R script
if you are ok with it.

First calculate an intermediate column [Baseline_Record] :

```
ValueForMax(Integer(Trim([Visit])='Baseline'),[Record]) over ([RecordId])
```

- This is calculated for every RecordId.
- *Trim([Visit])* removes extra spaces, just in case.
- *Trim([Visit])='Baseline'* will be True if the Visit is a Baseline,
  False otherwise.
- *Integer(..)* turns a logical True (False) into 1 (0). So the maximum
  value corresponds to the Baseline.
- *ValueForMax(col1,col2)* takes the value of col2 (in this case, Record)
  for the maximum value of col1.

So this will calculate a column that holds the Baseline record for every row.

Then to calculate the change you create another calculated column:

```
Abs([Record] - [Baseline_Record])
```

You could collapse everything into a single column, although not quite readable:

```
Abs([Record] - ValueForMax(Integer(Trim([Visit])='Baseline'),[Record]) over ([RecordId]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, based on the sample table you show:

```
library(dplyr)

your_data |>
  mutate(`Change in record from baseline` = abs(Record - first(Record)))
```

This assumes that the baseline value is the first one in each `RecordId` group. If this isn't the case, you could try `abs(Record - Record[Visit == "Baseline"])` instead of `abs(Record - first(Record))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked as well. Your response is much appreciated.